# Is it possible to change braces in Grafana or Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana

Grafana braces `{{ }}` collide with my Helm chart braces `{{ }}`.

1. Is it possible to change braces in **Grafana** from `{{ }}` to `{% %}`?
2. Is it possible to change braces in **Helm** from `{{ }}` to `{% %}`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the most straightforward way to do this is to provide the Grafana template data as a raw string in the Helm template, something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
name: stackoverflow-example
data:
  grafana.template: |-
    {{`{{ your-grafana.data.here }}`}}
```

In this case, the Helm template will only see the outer pair, and render the rest as an opaque string.

Comment: Fantastic answer, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped.

Comment: it is ugly but the workaround at the moment. give plus1 if you want this to be solved properly: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2798

Answer (score 0):

There is a better workaround than escaping the content with {{ }} and is using  **toJson**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-dashboards
data:
  compute.json:
{{ .Files.Get "dashboards/compute.json" | toJson | indent 4 }}
```

this avoids Go rendering the content of compute.json and puts the content there with the "{{variables}}" and everything.

be aware. Confimaps have a limitation of 1 MB. So do not abuse this. Otherwise, consider putting them on a repo and use something like this for GitLab (you can do it for any external URL / repo):

```yaml
    dashboards:
      default:
        your-dashboard-at-gitlab:
          url: "https://gitlab.yourdomain.com/api/v4/projects/9999/repository/files/yourfolder%2Fcompute.json/raw?ref=main"
```

Take a look to the values.yaml comments on the grafana chart [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L704).

There is also a github issue with this discussion [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2798).